# In BibDesk, change the cite key before importing from the web

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

When I use BibDesk, suppose I import a citation from a webpage. The cite key comes up automatically as `cite-key`. How can I change it before I actually add it to the bibliography?

I can always add it and then go back and change the cite key, but that's a pain.

To be clear, the image below shows the stage I'm at. If I click `import`, the reference is imported as is, with `cite-key` as the cite key. But I can't seem to change the cite key before I click import.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. How are you importing it? Just use **cmd-K** to generate a cite key.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell When I import it, it automatically gives it a cite key that I don't want. Then I can't change it before I add it. I have to add it with the useless cite key, then go back and change it.

Comment: This is a feature: BibDesk's parser (libbtparse) will reject data without a citekey, so BibDesk adds a dummy one for you. I'm still not sure how you're "importing" an item from a webpage since there are multiple methods, but I thought most of them finish off by automatically generating a citekey in your specified format (see BibDesk's preferences). The code has probably changed a lot since I last saw it, though.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell I'm importing it through the "web" tab, where you type in a web address (from arXiv, for instance) and it automatically generates a citation

Comment: In that case, there's no chance for manual intervention before it's imported, so your only option is to fix it afterwards. That's not too painful with cmd-k to generate it, but I'm surprised it's not automatically generating a key for you.

Comment: that's either a bug or a misfeature.

Comment: If no one comes up with a satisfying answer here, you may want to take this to the devs directly as a feature request. There is little point in adding ever increasing bounties if the program doesn't support this action you will not get a good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

There is an automated way to fix your citation keys after importation and for the entire bib file, using `bibtool` and entering one of the following commands in terminal, after you have install `bibtool`:

`bibtool -k BibFileIn.bib -o BibFileOut.bib`

`bibtool -K BibFileIn.bib -o BibFileOut.bib`

or

`bibtool -f "%n(author)%d(year)" BibFileIn.bib -o BibFileOut.bib`

These commands will take all the entries of your initial bib file `BibFileIn.bib` in my example and generate the new keys in a new bib file called `BibFileOut.bib`. For instance, the last command generates keys with the format **AuthorYear**

If you use the option `-f` you can tune the citation key generated to what you are used to.

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: you are posting a way to change *all* the keys, *after* they are generated; so you are not answering the question at all.